# How to extract href from links using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to get this links :

```
index.php?limitstart=0&amp;picno=0&amp;gallery_key=92
index.php?limitstart=0&amp;picno=1&amp;gallery_key=92
index.php?limitstart=0&amp;picno=2&amp;gallery_key=92
```

from this html using Jsoup :

```
<tr> 
<td style="padding: 8px;"><a onclick="redx_gallery_showImage(0);return false;" href="/module/gallery/index.php?limitstart=0&amp;picno=0&amp;gallery_key=92"><img width="90" height="90"  style='border: 1px #BAB9AF solid'   src='/redx_tools/mb_image.php/cid.077117104075119048121090118052048061/gid.10/pyrit_club_2_buche.jpg' border='1'    alt=''/></a></td> 
    <td style="padding: 8px;"><a onclick="redx_gallery_showImage(1);return false;" href="/module/gallery/index.php?limitstart=0&amp;picno=1&amp;gallery_key=92"><img width="90" height="90"  style='border: 1px #BAB9AF solid'   src='/redx_tools/mb_image.php/cid.085057100083102116053082117052115061/gid.10/pyrit_club_2_weiss.jpg' border='1'    alt=''/></a></td> 
    <td style="padding: 8px;"><a onclick="redx_gallery_showImage(2);return false;" href="/module/gallery/index.php?limitstart=0&amp;picno=2&amp;gallery_key=92"><img width="90" height="90"  style='border: 1px #BAB9AF solid'   src='/redx_tools/mb_image.php/cid.120068065087108097121088078055048061/gid.10/pyrit_club_2_wei_2.jpg' border='1'    alt=''/></a></td> 
</tr>
```

Any ideas? Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to know the `id` of a common container element so that you can get them all in a single CSS select. According to the [source](http://www.wippro.at/module/gallery/index.php?limitstart=0&picno=0&gallery_key=92) it's the `<div id="redx_gallery_thumb_list">`.

So, this should do:

```
Elements links = document.select("#redx_gallery_thumb_list a");

for (Element link : links) {
    String href = link.attr("href");

    // Or if you want to have absolute URL instead, so that you can leech them.
    String absUrl = link.absUrl("href");

    // ...
}
```