# Extracting a Link from within a JSoup <a> Tag with Attributes

Tags: java, html, jsoup

In an HTML document I have the following  tag

```
<a id="myUniqueID" class="myClassName" href="/uniqueURLToExtract" data-original-title"">This is a Title</a>
```

I'm using JSoup and would like to extract the URL contained in `href` identified by `myUniqueID`. After reading the following threads on SO

1. [Jsoup - extracting data from an <a> tag, inside a <td> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992325/jsoup-extracting-data-from-an-a-tag-inside-a-td-tag)
2. [JSoup parsing data from within a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105056/jsoup-parsing-data-from-within-a-tag)

I came up with this snippet of code

```
...
document = Jsoup.connect(mySiteAddress).timeout(10*1000).get();
...
String URLStr = document.select(a[id=myUniqueID]").text();
```

But all this does is print

```
This is a Title
```

I've tried other variations but they have not been successful. I've either got nothing printed or ended up with a null pointer exception.

I'm not sure how I would go about extracting the URL identified by the id `myUniqueID` in the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Is the early closed a tag a typo? `<a> id="myUniqueID" class="myClassName"...`

Comment: Check this answer, exactly what you need I guess : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6933687/2196341

Comment: @AdrianLynch Yes, it's a typo. Sorry about that. I fixed this in the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
String URLStr = document.select("a[id=myUniqueID]").attr("href");
```

So `attr()` over `text()`.

Comment: That should do it - more examples here - [Extract attributes, text, and HTML from elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

Comment: Thank you! This did it! Thanks also for the links!

Comment: When working with URLs, you generally want to do `.attr("abs:href")`. That makes sure the URL is absolute, not relative, regardless of what's in the source.

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the `href` attribute, and not the text of `a`:

```
String href = document.getElementById("myUniqueID").attr("href");
```

Comment: Thanks but I get the following error when I try it this way `The method get(String) is undefined for the type Element`.

Comment: Typo, I meant ``attr``

Comment: Cool! Thanks for clearing this up. Your solution works too. Glad to know there are at least a couple ways to solve this.

Comment: I favor ``getElementById`` since it return ``Element`` while ``document.select`` returns ``Elements``